# Read value Inside tags from xml using Batch Script

Tags: xml, tags, batch-file

Example : In test.xml, I have

```
   <head>
    <file name="input">
        <above>
              <tag point="x"/>
        </above>
        <below> 
              <result first="00"/>
        </below>
    </file>
    <file name="output">
        <above> 
              <tag point="y"/> 
        </above>
        <below> 
              <result first="11"/> 
        </below>
    </file>
   </head>
```

I should read this XML in batch script where i should get value "11" .
This "11" is found inside tag  in tag  in .

I have to get only the value "11" in the above specified path.

This is an example where in a real scenario there can be different value in place of "11".

Thanks in advance

Comment: One Suggession: Use Perl. It has many useful parsing modules like `HTML::Parser`, `DOM`, `SAX` etc. which will definetly resolve your all `HTML/XML` parssing issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FOR /F tokens^=2^ delims^=^" %%A in ('find "result first=" test.xml') do echo:%%A
```

or in command prompt:

```
fOR /F tokens^=2^ delims^=^" %A in ('find "result first=" test.xml') do echo:%A
```

this will work only if the structure of your file is as this above (specifically the new lines).
Better use xml startlet  http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/ . More info about the trick with the **for** - >

http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1544

http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1572